# Append dump to existing MySQL dump file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, dump

i need to Dump all data for 2 tables and a subset of data from another 2 tables in a MySQL database. So suppose i have tables t1,t2,t3,t4, I need full dump of t1 and t2 and get it using

```
mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t1 t2  > mydb_tables.sql
```

Now, i need to append this .sql file with dump for tables t3 ,t4 , but both are just subset of actual tables(like `SELECT * from t3 where id<1000`). Is it possible to append existing dump file `mydb_tables.sql`

Else, is there any method using which i can dump all 4 table data into a single file?

Comment: You can dump using ">>" instead of ">".

Comment: That worked! Please post it as answer and I will Mark this

Comment: Also, is there a way i can include all tables in a single statement?

Comment: (mysqldump dbname1 --tables table1; mysqldump dbname2 --tables table2) | > dump.sql

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use append method, like we append the regular files

```
eg:
    cat file2 >> file1
```

You can dump using **">>"** instead of **">"**

**">"** overwrites the destination file where as **">>"** appends to destination file.

```
mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t1 t2  > mydb_tables.sql

mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t3 t4  >> mydb_tables.sql
```